# ¿Cómo generar reportes en CSV con PHP y MySQL entre las fechas seleccionadas?

Tags: php, sql

Nunca tuve que generar un reporte en PHP y SQL, pero en este caso necesito hacerlo para exportarlo a Excel en CSV y generar un histograma.

Lo que quiero es buscar registros que se hayan registrado entre dos fechas, por ejemplo, en el mes de enero del 1 al 31.

El reporte se genera pero me muestra todos los registros que se han registrado tanto antes como después.

Mi código HTML es el siguiente:

```
<form action="reporte.php" method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 sclass">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="date" name="fechainc" placeholder="Fecha inicio: dd-mm-yyyy"
     maxlength="10" required>
          <br>
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="date" name="fechafin" placeholder="Fecha final: dd-mm-yyyy"
     maxlength="10" required>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name="reportar">Generar</button>
        </form>
```

Ese formulario usa el archivo `reporte.php` que contiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php
require ('conex.php');

//VARIABLES
$fecha1=$_POST['fechainc'];
$fecha2=$_POST['fechafin'];

if(isset($_POST['reportar']))
{
    // NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO Y CHARSET
    header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Reporte_Registros(PRISMA).csv"');

    // SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
    $salida=fopen('php://output', 'w');
    // ENCABEZADOS
    fputcsv($salida, array('ID Registro', 'Chasis', 'Acoplado', 'Operatoria', 'Sector', 'Producto', 'Datos Chofer', 'Datos Transporte', 'R.U.T.A. Chasis', 'R.U.T.A. Acoplado', 'R.T.O. Chasis', 'R.T.O. Acoplado', 'Extintor', 'Licencia', 'Empresa de Seguro', 'Seguro Chasis', 'Seguro Acoplado', 'Arrestallamas', 'E.P.P.', 'Estado Cisterna', 'Estado Check', 'Fecha Registro', 'Registro', 'Comentarios'),";");
    // QUERY PARA CREAR EL REPORTE
    $reporteCsv=$conex->query("SELECT * FROM registros WHERE fechaactual BETWEEN '$fecha1' AND '$fecha2' ORDER BY fechaactual DESC");
    while($filaR= $reporteCsv->fetch_assoc())
        fputcsv($salida, array($filaR['idregistros'], $filaR['patchasis'], $filaR['patacoplado'], $filaR['operatoria'], $filaR['sector'], $filaR['producto'], $filaR['datoschofer'], $filaR['datostransporte'], $filaR['rutachasis'], $filaR['rutaacoplado'], $filaR['vtochasis'], $filaR['vtoacoplado'], $filaR['extintor'], $filaR['licencia'], $filaR['nombreseguro'], $filaR['segurochasis'], $filaR['seguroacoplado'], $filaR['arrestallamas'], $filaR['epp'], $filaR['estadocisterna'], $filaR['estadocheck'], $filaR['fechaactual'], $filaR['registro'], $filaR['comentarios']),";");

}

?>
```

PD: cuando se registra un nuevo registro hay un campo llamado *Fecha de registro* el cual se guarda con un `input` de tipo `text` y el siguiente código:

```
$fechahoy = date('d-m-Y');
<input type="text" name="fechahoy" value="<?php echo $fechahoy; ?>" class="input-50" readonly="readonly">
```

Por medio de ese campo es el que yo quiero generar el reporte. Seleccionando entre dos fechas que el usuario desee buscar.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de campo es `fechaactual`? Por desgracia estás mezclando formatos de fecha. Un campo `<input type="text">` tiene texto libre, mientras que `<input type="date">` es `YYYY-mm-dd`, como un campo `DATE` de MySQL, aunque se muestre al usuario en formato local. Si confirmas el tipo de campo, y compartes algunos registros para poder reproducir un resultado, podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: me suena haber usado una consulta similar, y juraria que para hacer la comparacion de fechas tenia que poner: "WHEN DATE(fechaactual) BETWEEN $f1 and $f2"... tiene pinta de ser solo problema de consulta, pero sin ver un ejemplo de lo que te esta sacando tampoco te puedo decir mucho más /:

Comment: @AgusBellas , sin saber el tipo de campo no podemos hacer mucho más. Además, comparar sólo fechas es compatible con hacerlo con fechas y horas tanto a nivel de tipo de dato como a nivel de cadenas de caracteres. Por ejemplo, usar `DATE()` en un campo `TIMEDATE` solo trunca la parte de la hora.

Comment: @OscarGarcia , totalmente de acuerdo, ya he puesto que fue algo que me ocurriera a mi y que si todo funciona salvo la muestra de datos ya que el intervalo que devuelve no se encuentra entre los datos, tiene pinta de ser algo de la consulta. Yo sacaria la consulta sin ejecutarla para ver si alguno de los datos de la condicion no los esta recogiendo correctamente.

Comment: Yo apuesto más a que en la base de datos el tipo no es el correcto (está usando `VARCHAR` o similar en vez de `DATE`) y que eso interfiere entre el formato que envía el formulario (`aaaa-mm-dd`) con el que está almacenado en la base de datos que, en caso de estar en texto, posiblemente esté como `dd-mm-aaaa`.

Comment: Hola Imperus. ¿Has tenido tiempo de probar algo?

Comment: Perdón, que no pude verlo rápidamente, pero tengo mucho trabajo. el campo "fechaactual" en la base de datos si es de tipo "varchar", claro, debería pasarlo a tipo "date"? Lo que envío desde el formulario si es de tipo "text", porque si uso el tipo "date" no genera ningún registro, ahí debería estar el problema no? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a mezclar los formatos de fecha locales con los que se usan internamente tanto en la base de datos como en el navegador.

Voy a tratar de recomendarte cambios para que todo esté al mismo nivel de formato de datos de fecha.

### Base de datos

Para empezar, asumo que el campo `fechaactual` de la base de datos está correctamente configurado como `DATE` y no como un texto genérico (`VARCHAR`, `CHAR`, `TEXT`, etc).

En caso de no estarlo habrá que migrar la información almacenada al formato correcto de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE registros
SET fechaactual = STR_TO_DATE(fechaactual, '%d-%m-%Y');

ALTER TABLE registros
  MODIFY fechaactual DATE;
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea en [este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56ZA29M6QAD7AezVkLUV58/0).

En la primera instrucción SQL hago una conversión de la cadena que se encuentra en formato, por ejemplo, `dd-mm-aaaa` al formato `aaaa-mm-dd` que se espera en un campo `DATE`.

En la segunda instrucción convierto el campo a tipo `DATE` (que sería lo idóneo).

### Fecha actual

Debes pensar que un [`<input type="date" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date#Valor) muestra al usuario la fecha en configuración local, pero internamente la almacena y debes indicarla en formato `aaaa-mm-dd`:

```
<input type="date" name="fechahoy" value="<?= date('Y-m-d') ?>" class="input-50" readonly>
```

Si usas un campo de tipo `<input type="text" />` y permites al usuario hacer uso de un formato de fecha local, no podrás usar esa fecha en una consulta SQL si los campos están en formatos `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc porque en la base de datos se representan como `aaaa-mm-dd` o `aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

### Formulario

En este caso te recomiendo no hacer mención del formato local. Usuarios que tengan el sistema operativo en otra configuración local podrían tener problemas para que el navegador valide la fecha como tú indicas.

Tampoco pondría el atributo `maxlength` y al botón no le daría valor (para que no sea enviado un texto del que no harás uso):

```
<form action="reporte.php" method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 sclass">
  <input type="date" name="fechainc" placeholder="Fecha inicio" required class="form-control mr-sm-2"><br/>
  <input type="date" name="fechafin" placeholder="Fecha final" required class="form-control mr-sm-2">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Generar</button>
</form>
```

### Script PHP

En el script PHP he hecho varios cambios que están comentados en el código:

```
<?php
/* Una construcción del lenguaje no requiere paréntesis, no tiene parámetros */
require 'conex.php';

/* Antes de hacer uso de variables POST comprobamos su existencia */
if(empty($_POST['fechainc']) === false
  && empty($_POST['fechafin']) === false
) {
  /* Escapamos las fechas para evitar inyección SQL */
  $fecha1 = $conex->real_escape_string($_POST['fechainc']);
  $fecha2 = $conex->real_escape_string($_POST['fechafin']);

  /* Enviamos las cabeceras para la descarga del archivo */
  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Reporte_Registros(PRISMA).csv"');

  $salida = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
  fputcsv(
    $salida,
    array(
      'ID Registro',
      'Chasis',
      'Acoplado',
      'Operatoria',
      'Sector',
      'Producto',
      'Datos Chofer',
      'Datos Transporte',
      'R.U.T.A. Chasis',
      'R.U.T.A. Acoplado',
      'R.T.O. Chasis',
      'R.T.O. Acoplado',
      'Extintor',
      'Licencia',
      'Empresa de Seguro',
      'Seguro Chasis',
      'Seguro Acoplado',
      'Arrestallamas',
      'E.P.P.',
      'Estado Cisterna',
      'Estado Check',
      'Fecha Registro',
      'Registro',
      'Comentarios'
    ),
    ";"
  );

  /* Ahora puedo usar las variables ya que el contenido ha sido escapado a SQL */
  $reporteCsv = $conex->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM registros
    WHERE fechaactual BETWEEN '$fecha1' AND '$fecha2'
    ORDER BY fechaactual DESC
  ");

  /* Procura hacer uso SIEMPRE de las llaves {} aunque sólo haya una instrucción */
  while ($filaR = $reporteCsv->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv(
      $salida,
      array(
        $filaR['idregistros'],
        $filaR['patchasis'],
        $filaR['patacoplado'],
        $filaR['operatoria'],
        $filaR['sector'],
        $filaR['producto'],
        $filaR['datoschofer'],
        $filaR['datostransporte'],
        $filaR['rutachasis'],
        $filaR['rutaacoplado'],
        $filaR['vtochasis'],
        $filaR['vtoacoplado'],
        $filaR['extintor'],
        $filaR['licencia'],
        $filaR['nombreseguro'],
        $filaR['segurochasis'],
        $filaR['seguroacoplado'],
        $filaR['arrestallamas'],
        $filaR['epp'],
        $filaR['estadocisterna'],
        $filaR['estadocheck'],
        $filaR['fechaactual'],
        $filaR['registro'],
        $filaR['comentarios']
      ),
      ";"
    );
  }
}
/* No es necesario ni recomendable cerrar la etiqueta si sólo hay código PHP */
```

Resalto una de las modificación más importantes: para evitar los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) relacionados con la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), deberías usar (por ejemplo) la función [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.real-escape-string) para escapar el contenido de las variables a SQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he leído con atención toda la información que me has brindado, hice algunas correcciones y demás, pero tengo un error " fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in", que básicamente me lo genera en la linea donde esta el ";", intente cambiarle las comillas por simples pero el error persiste. Lo siento si es algo muy obvio pero no puedo darme cuenta que es.

Comment: Te lo da al final, pero es el primer parámetro, `STDOUT`, el que falla. Debes usar `$salida = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');` como antes, si no se usa php-cli esa contante no está definida.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, ahora funciona de maravilla, muy amable al responder, me has ayudado como no te imaginas. Saludos y exitos!

Comment: Ya he editado la respuesta para ponerlo correctamente. Un placer ser de ayuda :)

Comment: ¿Qué era lo que te ocurría? ¿Era el formato de las fechas almacenado en la base de datos?

Comment: El problema es que enviaba la información de modo "text" y SQL la recibía de modo "date", entonces los datos no coincidían. Cambie los campos a tipo "date" (que es donde el usuario ingresa los datos). Y ademas cambié el campo "fechaactual" a tipo "date" que también estaba en tipo "text". Muchas gracias.